# Converting blocking code to using scala futures

Tags: scala, asynchronous

My old code looks something like below, where all db calls blocking.

I need help converting this over to using Futures.

```
def getUserPoints(username: String): Option[Long]
    db.getUserPoints(username) match {
        case Some(userPoints) => Some(userPoints.total)
        case None => {
            if (db.getSomething("abc").isEmpty) {
                db.somethingElse("asdf") match {
                    case Some(pointId) => {
                        db.setPoints(pointId, username)
                        db.findPointsForUser(username)
                    }
                    case _ => None
                }
            } else {
                db.findPointsForUser(username)
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

My new API is below where I am returning Futures.

```
db.getUserPoints(username: String): Future[Option[UserPoints]]
db.getSomething(s: String): Future[Option[Long]]
db.setPoints(pointId, username): Future[Unit]
db.findPointsForUser(username): Future[Option[Long]]
```

How can I go about converting the above to use my new API that uses futures.

I tried using a for-compr but started to get wierd errors like Future[Nothing].

```
var userPointsFut: Future[Long] = for {
  userPointsOpt <- db.getUserPoints(username)
  userPoints <- userPointsOpt
} yield userPoints.total
```

But it gets a bit tricky with all the branching and if clauses and trying to convert it over to futures.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that the first issue with this design is that the port of the blocking call to a `Future` should not wrap the Option type:

The blocking call: 
`def giveMeSomethingBlocking(for:Id): Option[T]`
Should become:
`def giveMeSomethingBlocking(for:Id): Future[T]`
And *not*:
`def giveMeSomethingBlocking(for:Id): Future[Option[T]]`

The blocking call give either a value `Some(value)` or `None`,  the non-blocking Future version gives either a `Success(value)`  or `Failure(exception)` which fully preserves the `Option` semantics in a non-blocking fashion.

With that in mind, we can model the process in question using combinators on `Future`. Let's see how:

First, lets refactor the API to something we can work with:

```
type UserPoints = Long
object db {
  def getUserPoints(username: String): Future[UserPoints] = ???
  def getSomething(s: String): Future[UserPoints] = ???
  def setPoints(pointId:UserPoints, username: String): Future[Unit] = ???
  def findPointsForUser(username: String): Future[UserPoints] = ???
}
class PointsNotFound extends Exception("bonk")
class StuffNotFound extends Exception("sthing not found")
```

Then, the process would look like:

```
def getUserPoints(username:String): Future[UserPoints] = {
  db.getUserPoints(username)
  .map(userPoints => userPoints /*.total*/)
  .recoverWith{ 
    case ex:PointsNotFound => 
    (for {
      sthingElse <- db.getSomething("abc")
      _ <- db.setPoints(sthingElse, username)
      points <- db.findPointsForUser(username)
    } yield (points))
    .recoverWith{
      case ex: StuffNotFound => db.findPointsForUser(username)
    }
  }
}
```

Which type-checks correctly.

### Edit

---

Given that the API is set in stone, a way to deal with nested monadic types is to define a MonadTransformer. In simple words, let's make `Future[Option[T]]` a new monad, let's call it `FutureO` that can be composed with other of its kind. [1]

```
case class FutureO[+A](future: Future[Option[A]]) {
  def flatMap[B](f: A => FutureO[B])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): FutureO[B] = {
    val newFuture = future.flatMap{
      case Some(a) => f(a).future
      case None => Future.successful(None)
    }
    FutureO(newFuture)
  }

  def map[B](f: A => B)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): FutureO[B] = {
    FutureO(future.map(option => option map f))
  }
  def recoverWith[U >: A](pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, FutureO[U]])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): FutureO[U] = {
    val futOtoFut: FutureO[U] => Future[Option[U]] = _.future
    FutureO(future.recoverWith(pf andThen futOtoFut))
  }

  def orElse[U >: A](other: => FutureO[U])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): FutureO[U] = {
      FutureO(future.flatMap{
        case None => other.future
        case _ => this.future
      }) 
    }
  }
```

And now we can re-write our process preserving the same structure as the future-based composition.

```
type UserPoints = Long 
object db { 
  def getUserPoints(username: String): Future[Option[UserPoints]] = ???
  def getSomething(s: String): Future[Option[Long]] = ???
  def setPoints(pointId: UserPoints, username:String): Future[Unit] = ???
  def findPointsForUser(username: String): Future[Option[Long]] = ???
}
class PointsNotFound extends Exception("bonk")
class StuffNotFound extends Exception("sthing not found")

def getUserPoints2(username:String): Future[Option[UserPoints]] = {
  val futureOpt = FutureO(db.getUserPoints(username))
  .map(userPoints => userPoints /*.total*/)
  .orElse{ 
    (for {
      sthingElse <- FutureO(db.getSomething("abc"))
      _ <- FutureO(db.setPoints(sthingElse, username).map(_ => Some(())))
      points <- FutureO(db.findPointsForUser(username))
    } yield (points))
    .orElse{
      FutureO(db.findPointsForUser(username))
    }
  }
  futureOpt.future
}
```

[1] with acknowledgements to http://loicdescotte.github.io/posts/scala-compose-option-future/

Comment: I can't really change Future[Option[UserPoints]], my library returns Future Option.

Comment: @coolbreeze I've added an approach that preserves the same compositional structure on the `Future[Option[T]]`

Comment: I realized a flaw in my previous answer. Given that you want to recover when the returned value is `Future(None)` we need another combinator `orElse` which I've introduced. Updated the rest of the answer accordingly.

Comment: You should not post answer in your question. Post it as "Answer".

Comment: @talex I cannot understand the reason of your comment. Care to explain?

Comment: As far as I understand your edit section is actually answer to your question. If this is the case you should press "Answer" button. It is tradition (and I believe rules) of this site.

Comment: @talex I think you are confused friend. This is an answer to the question above. The edit part was added after the OP (original poster) commented that he cannot change the API, so I offered an alternative *answer* in the Edited section to comply with the requirements.

Comment: I thought I post under question, but it is already answer. Shame on me. Sorry for my remissness. I'm stupid idiot :(

Comment: @talex Don't worry. We all have our days :-)